# The distance between two “close” matrices under the same orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

Suppose that $A=\left(a_{ij}\right)\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a symmetric matrix with positive entries. Let $$\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2 \dots \geq \lambda_n$$
be the eigenvalues of $A$.
Thus there exists an orthogonal matrix $C$ such that
\begin{equation*}
A= 
C^t\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_{n} 
\end{pmatrix}C .
\end{equation*}

**My question is when I change some $\lambda_i$'s slightly, can we still obtain a symmetric matrix with positive entries under the same transformation continuous.**

For example, we consider changing one eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ to $\lambda_1+\epsilon$.
Denote
\begin{equation*}
B=\left(b_{ij}\right):= 
C^t\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_{1}+\epsilon & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_{2} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_{n} 
\end{pmatrix}C.
\end{equation*}
Can we find a sufficiently small $\epsilon$ such that **$B$ is still a symmetric matrix with positive entries**.
I also wonder what the **distance between $A$ and $B$**, that is,
can
$$\sum_{i,j}(a_{ij}-b_{ij})^2$$
tends to $0$ as $\epsilon$ tends to $0$.

---

I don't know whether there is a general solution to this question. I think this can be right but I don't know how to prove it.
Any help will be appreciated.:)

Comment: This clearly is not always possible. Perhaps you should require that $A$ is entrywise positive.

Comment: For your second question: because $C$ is orthogonal, the distance is simply $|\epsilon|$.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, the condition is $A$ entrywise positive (I have edited the question). In this case, is it an easy fact?

Comment: @VerMoriarty Yes: this is a consequence of the fact that the entries of $B$ are a continuous function of $\epsilon$.  Specifically, it is enough to take $|\epsilon| < \min_{i,j} |a_{ij}|$.